# Group By date in User's Timezone stored as Datetime format

Tags: android, sqlite, date, datetime, android-sqlite

I have stored date time values and I have values like this:

```
id     |      timestamp     |
"6003"  "2016-06-21 14:48:34"
"6002"  "2016-06-21 17:18:34"
"6001"  "2016-06-21 19:48:34"
"6000"  "2016-06-21 22:18:34"
"5999"  "2016-06-22 00:48:34"
"5998"  "2016-06-22 03:18:34"
"5997"  "2016-06-22 05:48:34"
"5996"  "2016-06-22 08:18:34"
...
...
```

This all are stored in UTC (as I used CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to store value).

Now I want to count total no of records per day as per user's timezone and not GMT.

Like output should be

```
2016-06-21    20
2016-06-22    18
2016-06-23    17
2016-06-24    35
...
```

The count should calculated based on date in user's timezone.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it. It wasn't too difficult.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT date(datetime(timestamp, 'localtime')), count(*) FROM log_time 
          GROUP BY date(datetime(timestamp, 'localtime'))
```